# Using Razor Syntax within JavaScript Conditional Statment

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, conditional-statements

In an index.cshtml I have the following working code similar to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

if ('@Model.SomeCondition' === 'True'){
Do Something();
}

</script>
```

The `=== 'True'` seems like an odd hack to me to force Razor and JavaScript to get along. How can I refactor to use `=== true`? This doesn't give the same result. Can this be done with Razor and JavaScript?

Comment: Mixing Razor and Javascript is a bad idea.  You should separate data from code using `data-*` attributes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the property is`bool`, you can check in razor if condition following way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@if (Model.SomeCondition){
@:Do Something();
}
</script>
```

or:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@if (Model.SomeCondition){
<text>
Do Something();
</text>
}    
</script>
```

Comment: This will, of course, evaluate the boolean in server code and only output the javascript if true. In some ways a better solution than turning a server boolean into a client-side boolean.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `SomeCondition` is a string, remove the quotes, and make it conform to the lowercase form of javascript's booleans

```
<script language="javascript">
    // just to be clear this is javascript, not server code
    if (@Model.SomeCondition.ToLowerInvariant()){
        .. // 
    }
</script>
```

If, however `SomeCondition` is a boolean in server code, you need to first convert to a string and make it lowercase

```
<script language="javascript">
    // just to be clear this is javascript, not server code
    if (@Model.SomeCondition.ToString().ToLowerInvariant()){
        .. // 
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write the if satement in c#/razor with the javascript you want to execute in there.

Example:

```
@if(boolVariable)
{
    <script>
        //javascript here
    </script>
}
```

Comment: That's fine if that's the _only_ JavaScript you want to run, but if it's part of a larger block it doesn't really work

Comment: Well, assuming this was going inside of already declared <script> tags, just use ViewContext.Writer.Write("javascript here").  This isn't a good scenario to be in to begin with, this is just a solution without refactoring everything.